# Finding closest date in a list before the input date

Tags: c#, date

I found this code for finding the closest date in a date range

```
    var inputDate = UserInputDate;
    List<DateTime> allDates = new List<DateTime>();
    allDates.add(date1);
    allDates.add(date2);
    allDates.add(date3);

    var closestDate = inputDate >= allDates.Last()
        ? allDates.Last()
        : inputDate <= allDates.First()
            ? allDates.First()
            : allDates.First(d => d >= inputDate);
```

However this codes finds the closest date that is after the input date.

What i need is the closest date before the inputDate

I honestly do not understand this code and 
I tried changing the >= to <= and .Last to .First but it didn't worked the way I wanted it to

Comment: It seems like in order to work this code requires the list to be sorted.

Comment: Assuming it isn't presorted, though, it wouldn't make sense to sort it now. Sorting would take a lot of overhead vs. what is effectively creating a sort of priority queue with max length of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by constructing a filtered list of all items less than the input date, and then taking the max value:

```
var closestDate = allDates.Where(x => x < inputDate).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
```

`Where` will filter to only leave all dates that are smaller than `inputDate`, and `Max` will then choose the largest one left.

If you think that the list may be empty, you can either use `DefaultIfEmpty()` before the `Max` (which will give you `default(DateTime)` as its result if the list is empty. You can also split this up:

```
var possibleDates = allDates.Where(x => x < inputDate);
if (possibleDates.Any())
{
    var closestDate = possibleDates.Max();
}
```

*However*, if `allDates` is already in sorted order in memory, then you could simply do:

```
var closestDate = allDates.TakeWhile(x => x < inputDate).Last();
```

`TakeWhile` will choose the elements that are smaller than `inputDate` as well, but stops after it finds one that is larger. (This makes sense if it is presorted.)

Again, to handle an empty list, you could use `LastOrDefault` or the same `Any` pattern as above.

Comment: Hi David, not sure if you will see this however I came across a problem while using this code. For allDates if I add lets say 4 10 15 20. And closestDate is on the 4th. The code somehow crashes

Answer (score 1):

**If** the list is sorted you could use the [BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function which returns

> The zero-based index of item in the sorted List, if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement of the index of the next element that is larger than item or, if there is no larger element, the bitwise complement of Count.

```
int pos = allDates.BinarySearch(inputDate);
if (pos < 0)
    pos = ~pos - 1;

var closestDate = allDates[pos];
```

To explain the code in your question it basically says

Take the last item if the item you're searching for is greater than the last date in the list

```
var closestDate = inputDate >= allDates.Last()
? allDates.Last()
```

Otherwise if the input date is lower than the first item, take the first item

```
: inputDate <= allDates.First()
    ? allDates.First()
```

Otherwise take the first item that's greater than or equal to the input date

```
: allDates.First(d => d >= inputDate);
```

If you want to just reverse the logic from your question you need the last line to take the *last* item that's less than your input. Note that this reliese on the list being sorted still though:

```
var closestDate = inputDate >= allDates.Last()
    ? allDates.Last()
    : inputDate <= allDates.First()
        ? allDates.First()
        : allDates.Last(d => d <= inputDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

Order them descending, then take the first one that meets your criteria:

```
var closest = allDates.OrderByDescending(x => x).First(x => x <= inputDate);
```

Comment: Sorting the list just to choose one is very inefficient.

Comment: Not worth a downvote though IMHO.  Nothing has been said about efficiency in the question, and unless OP is undertaking a massive list, it's negligable, though certainly worth noting